# When the name of a chat room ends in a space, formatting breaks

Tags: bug, chat

[Example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9517687#9517687):

> 12 messages moved to [Islam and Judaism dialogue](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8758/islam-and-judaism-dialogue)

```
12 messages moved to [Islam and Judaism dialogue ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8758/islam-and-judaism-dialogue)
```

The extra space does not break the link here on the site itself, but it does in chat, even in system messages like the one above. Proposed solution: do not allow the names of chat rooms to end with spaces.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Screenshot? pretty please

Comment: Click the link marked "Example", @hjpotter92. The bug still shows there. (But I've added an image anyway.)