# Terminal spaces in Area 51 proposal names break question formatting

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

When a proposal name ends in a space, that space should be trimmed. Currently, it is kept, which breaks the formatting of questions about that proposal. The [Sage proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70511/sage) at Area 51 is actually called “Sage ”, with a trailing space, which means that when you ask a question about it, the body is prefilled with `Proposal: [**Sage **][1]`, which does not render with the desired bold type.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181086/147191.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the next A51 build, we'll trim the proposal title to avoid storing leading or trailing spaces.

I also fixed up currently not-deleted proposals with trailing spaces in the title.